# In pytorch loss is the value nn.MSELoss(yhat, y), you can then call loss.data[0], what does that do?

Tags: pytorch

I am following a tutorial from GitHub and I am confused on this piece of code. I am trying to find documentation for it but I couldn't find any. I tried to trace my way back to nn.MSELoss as well. What does indexing into loss.data[0] do? What about the other indexes?

`criterion = nn.MSELoss()`

`loss = criterion(pred, y)`

`print('loss: ', loss.data[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Right after I post this I find the answer...

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/confused-about-loss-data-0/1572